# "the pressure of population " VS "the pressure of the population"

Tags: definite-article

> 1. The pressure of population on available resources is the key to understanding history.
> 2. The pressure of **the** population on available resources is the key to understanding history.

As far as I can see, population is a countable noun, so there should always be an article before it. So I am confusing about the drop of "the" here.

Comment: 'Population', like 'people', is not a count noun, unless you quantify it; and 'the population' is not necessarily more countable than 'the sand' or 'the water'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "population" in the first context is uncountable. It does not refer to any one specific group of people, so the definite article is not appropriate. Think of "population" here as meaning "population size".

If we say "the pressure of **the** population", then we are referring to one specific population, such as the population of London or the population of a particular animal species on an island. In that case, it would make sense to specify "history" as well, because we must also be talking about that population's history:

> The pressure of **the** population on available resources is the key to understanding **its** history.